# Netty: Boss Event Loop and Executor

Tags: java, netty, event-loop

In most of the examples that i have currently using Netty, I see that boss executor is a cached threadpool. From what i understand the event loop should only have a single thread, why exactly do we need a cached threadpool for the boss event loop?

Answer (score 13):

Netty has the concept of `EventLoopGroup` which aggregates several `EventLoop`s. An `EventLoop` is single threaded, the `EventLoopGroup` is mostly not. Unless you're doing old blocking I/O.

Now, what concerns boss vs. workers. Assuming you're talking about a server implementation, the boss is now called `parentGroup` and the workers `childGroup`. The parent handles the I/O for the acceptor channel, i.e. the one which is bounded to the port where your server is accepting new requests. The children will the handling the I/O for the accepted connections. Indeed the acceptor channel should be handled by one and only thread and it will. If you pass a `EventLoopGroup` with several `EventLoop`s to the parent, it will only use one of the `EventLoop`s anyway, so a good practice is to reuse the same `EventLoopGroup` for both parent and child.

The `ServerBootstrap` actually provides two constructors, one that takes a single group and reuses it for both parent and client:

```
@Override
public ServerBootstrap group(EventLoopGroup group) {
    return group(group, group);
}
```

and one that allows you to explicitly pass the one for the parent and the one for the child:

```
public ServerBootstrap group(EventLoopGroup parentGroup, EventLoopGroup childGroup) {
    super.group(parentGroup);
    if (childGroup == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("childGroup");
    }
    if (this.childGroup != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("childGroup set already");
    }
    this.childGroup = childGroup;
    return this;
}
```

You can check it here: https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/transport/src/main/java/io/netty/bootstrap/ServerBootstrap.java

Comment: this does not quite actually answer my question. What is the purpose of cachedThreadpool for a eventloop with one thread?

Comment: The explanation applies for Netty 4.x and above. If you look at the EventLoop hierarchy there, every EventLoop implementation extends SingleThreadEventLoop (apart from EmbeddedEventLoop, which would be mainly used for unit testing). If you can provide a link to the examples you saw, it will probably be easier to answer your question.

Comment: the link you post is gone, here is the newest one [link](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/eb7f751ba519cbcab47d640cd18757f09d077b55/transport/src/main/java/io/netty/bootstrap/ServerBootstrap.java)